# Show value in tags and autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-textext

I have integrated [this](http://textextjs.com/) for auto complete with tags input. The script I am using is below

```
$('#textarea').textext({
        plugins : 'tags focus autocomplete ajax',
        tagsItems : [ 'Skoda, BMW, Audi' ],
        ajax : {
            url : '/manual/examples/data.json',
            dataType : 'json',
            cacheResults : true
        }
    });
```

Here the value `'Skoda, BMW, Audi'` is passed from PHP variable. On page load I can not show these values already selected in `tags` format. How can I pass the value `'Skoda, BMW, Audi'` in below format

```
'Skoda', 'BMW', 'Audi'
```

so that it gets displayed in `tagsItems`. Also when I search, it keeps on calling my `ajax URL` in a loop and without any result.

Feel free to suggest any better plugin for autocomplete with tags input ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case is that you are not getting a returned value-
the example one the site is not complete- the tags are stored in a .json file ([here](http://textextjs.com/manual/examples/data.json)). 
The url of this file is defined here-

```
 url : '/manual/examples/data.json',
```

You should create your own file with the tags you would like to allow, and change the url accordingly.

Comment: The above file is for reference purpose only. I have already created my json file with return values.